# Connect Exception with Jakarta Mail on a Windows Server

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-mail, windows-server

I'm trying to add Jakarta Mail to my Spring Boot app. I have tested the app on my local computer and got a 200 OK and an Email in my Inbox, GREAT!
Now I'm testing the app on a Windows Server, but I get a connection exception (the response is still 200 OK).

When I run the DEBUG SMTP I get this:

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=outlook.office365.com, user=admin, password=<null>
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 25, isSSL true
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: outlook.office365.com, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Im not sure what is going wrong.

```
// Set Email Properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", config.getHost());
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", config.getPort());
        properties.put("mail.debug", "true");

        // Get Email Server Access
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication( config.getUsername(),config.getPassword() );
            }
        };

        // Start Email Session
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(config.getFrom()));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(config.getTo()));
            message.setSubject(subject);

            // Build Message Body Object
            BodyPart emailBody = new MimeBodyPart();
            emailBody.setText(body);

            // Build Email Attachment Object
            MimeBodyPart emailAttachment = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource("file.pdf");
            emailAttachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            emailAttachment.setFileName("file.pdf");

            // Merge Email Object
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(emailBody );
            multipart.addBodyPart(emailAttachment);
            message.setContent(multipart );

            // Create a new transport with the Jakarta Mail properties
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();
        transport.connect(config.getUsername(), config.getPassword());

        // Send the message
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Things I tried:

- Use port 587 instead of 25
- Enabled/Disabled: mail.smtp.ssl.enable
- Run "ping outlook.office365.com", in the Command Prompt
- Checked if Windows Defender Firewall allow Tomcat9
- Test with Telnet, but throws IOExcoption Connection timed out: connect